# Run program compiled using Intel Fortran 8.1 for Windows under WinXP with 64-bit Windows 10 system

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, compatibility

I need to run a program that was compiled using Intel Fortran 8.1 for Windows under WinXP with 64-bit Windows 10 system.

This are the instructions that came with the program:

Model run:

Put all 3 files (model.exe file + YOURFILE + METFILE) in the same directory, open the directory in the Windows Explorer and type in the command line (press "Windows key"+R to call the command window):

model < YOURFILE >,

where < YOURFILE > is the name of Your namelist configuration file.

This is what I get:
"Windows cannot find ´model´. Make sure yout typed name correctly,and then try again"

I have also tried to run the program inside the directory but nothing happens.

**This is a compatibility problem?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you do have compatibility issues; many Windows XP programs will not work under Windows 10, and programs that were originally written and compiled as 16-bit executables will definitely not run under Windows 10. However, the message you are receiving does not indicate a compatibility issue; the instructions you were given for running the program under Windows 10 are incorrect.

1. Copy `model.exe`, the namelist file, and the metfile into the same directory on the Windows 10 system. It would be best if the directory did not contain spaces anywhere in the path. For the rest of these instructions, I will assume that you have copied them into `C:\MODEL`.
2. Open a command prompt (<kbd>Win (⊞)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>)
3. Type `cd /d c:\model`<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>
4. Type `model namelist`<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> (where `namelist` is the name of your namelist file - `YOURFILE` in the original instructions)

If this does not solve your problem, you will need to contact the supplier of the program for further support.

Comment: Problem solved thank you so much...